# Subspaces in linear algebra - Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace, dimension-theory-algebra

> Let $S=$ {$a_{ij} \in M_{3}(\mathbb{R}):a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{13}=a_{21}+a_{22}+a_{23}=a_{31}+a_{32}+a_{33}$}

$S$ is a subspace of $M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ and dim $S = 7$

I tought I could arrive somewhere with the determinand but that led me nowhere. Any other ideas?

Comment: "Is it right to say that:  is a subspace of 3(ℝ) and dim =7": Well... if you can prove it yes, otherwise, no...

Comment: It is a subspace of $M_3$. You can prove it by looking at the criteria for a subspace: it has to contain a zero, be closed under addition and be closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take $V=\mathbb R^9$. Then consider the matrix
$$ M=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 1&1&-1&-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then $S$ is the kernel of this matrix ($Mx=0$ if and only if $x_1+x_2+x_3 = x_4+x_5+x_6 = x_7+x_8+x_9$).

As $M$ has rank $2$, corank $7$ the kernel has dimension $7$.